# Erro código repetindo valores na threads?

Tags: c, thread, pthreads

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *Operacao(void *soma) {
int n;
printf(“Digite o primeiro numero:”);
scanf("%d", &n);
printf(“Digite o segundo numero:”);
scanf("%d", &n);
printf(“A soma e:%d”, n + n);
pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main() {
pthread_t thread;
int flag;

printf(“Criando uma nova thread\n”);
flag = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, Operacao, NULL);
if (flag != 0)
printf(“Erro na criação de uma nova thread\n”);
Operacao(NULL);
pthread_exit(NULL);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Qual linguagem? c++?

Comment: Atenção as aspas que não são aspas normais que se usam em programação e sim aspas de um editor de texto tipo *Microsoft Word*. Aproveite essa correção e acerte também a indentação para facilitar a leitura.

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem alguns problemas:

- Você está usando em alguns lugares `“aspas inglesas”` ao invés de `"aspas duplas comuns"`. Isso daí não compila. Entretanto, isso também é muito fácil de se arrumar.
- A sua função `Operacao` não utiliza o callback `soma` para nada. E esse callback é sempre `NULL`.
- A chamada à `pthread_exit` na função `main` é desnecessária porque a função `Operacao` já faz isso.
- Na sua função operação, você lê o número duas vezes, mas armazena ambos os números lidos na mesma posição de memória `n`. Dessa forma, a primeira leitura será descartada e apenas o resultado da segunda será utilizado. Como você exibe `n + n` depois, irá exibir o dobro do segundo valor lido.
- Não é boa prática (e o compilador pode te dar uma *warning*) não usar o `return` em uma função cujo tipo de retorno não é `void` (e lembre-se que `void *` não é o mesmo que `void`), mesmo se não existir forma possível pela qual a função poderia finalizar a sua execução normalmente. A solução é colocar um `return NULL;` na função `Operacao`. Isso não altera o funcionamento dessa função, mas serve para deixar o compilador satisfeito nos casos onde ele venha a reclamar disso.

Acho que o que você queria era isso:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *operacao() {
    int a, b;
    printf("Digite o primeiro número: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("Digite o segundo número: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("A soma é %d.", a + b);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL; // Nunca é executado.
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    printf("Criando uma nova thread\n");
    int flag = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, operacao);
    if (flag != 0) {
        printf("Erro na criação de uma nova thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
    operacao();
    return 0;
}
```

Ou, se quiser informar qual é a thread na hora de pedir a entrada para o usuário:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void *operacao(const char *nome_thread) {
    int a, b;
    printf("A thread %s pede que você digite o primeiro número: ", nome_thread);
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("A thread %s pede que você digite o segundo número: ", nome_thread);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("A soma é %d.", a + b);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
    return NULL; // Nunca é executado.
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread;
    printf("Criando uma nova thread\n");
    int flag = pthread_create(&thread, NULL, operacao, "auxiliar");
    if (flag != 0) {
        printf("Erro na criação de uma nova thread\n");
        return 1;
    }
    operacao("principal");
    return 0;
}
```

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/kXlerf)

Comment: Valeu muito obrigado

Comment: @FutebolArtsVariados Se essa resposta resolveu o seu problema e não restou nenhuma dúvida, marque-a como correta/aceita ao clicar no "✅" que está ao lado dela, o que também marca a sua pergunta como resolvida. Se ainda te resta alguma dúvida ou gostaria de maiores esclarecimentos, fique a vontade para comentar. 

Comment: boa resposta, mas eu fiz de uma forma diferente e deu certo , baseado no seu código .Obrigado ai .